# Can't upload files larger than 2mb from Angular to Django rest framework

Tags: django, angular, nginx, upload

I want to be able to upload audio files of any size from an Angular website to Django backend.
At the moment i am able to upload small files up to ~2mb without any problems, however, when uploading files larger than 2mb the Django function that handles the file upload doesn't fire, and no errors occur in Angular frontend.

Angular

```
uploadFile() {
    this.subscription = this.ApiService.uploadfile(this.fileToUpload,this.myControl.value).subscribe(data => {
      this.UtilsService.openSnackBar('Successfully added wavs',this.myControl.value)
        // do something, if upload success
        alert("success")
      }, error => {
        //console.log(error);
        alert("error")
      });
      this.dialogRef.close();
  }
```

Upload function of ApiService, sends some parameters along with file(s)

```
uploadfile(file,inst_label):Observable<any>{
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    for(let i = 0; i < file.length; i++){
      if(i==0){
        formData.append(inst_label,file[i],file[i].name)
      }
      else{
        formData.append(i.toString(),file[i],file[i].name)
      }
      
    }
    return this.http.post(this.baseurl + '/upload_files', formData);
  }
```

On my settings.py i have set:

```
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 5000000000 # 50 MB
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 5000000000 # 50 MB
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o644
```

Lastly my function upload_files in views.py  prints something when files are less than 2mb, if the files are >2mb nothing happens.

Hope i was clear enough, i'm running out of ideas on what to do besides cut those large files to smaller ones before uploading.

Comment: How does your communication between angular and django looks like ? is it the same network for example in docker-compose ? is it over API through domain ?

Comment: The communication between both frameworks is over API through domain.
For development i use the same network, in production i also added this line "client_max_body_size 50M" to my nginx settings.
This feature is for developers only so you can assume it will only be used in the same network.